# Positioning and Aligning Objects in Navbar CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to have the links that are currently on the side move to the the top and be aligned as they are in a regular nav bar.

Like this:
[Rough Illustration of Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6bxQ.jpg)

Instead of how it currently is all bunched up in the side.

Current code: https://jsfiddle.net/58dn7rw7/

```
#mySidenav a {
    position: fixed;
    right: -90px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 120px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 100px 0 0 10px;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#mySidenav a:hover {
    right: 0;
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I may not get what you are saying but in the fiddle you are positioning the the elements using top. Can you not change the top values to what you want to spread them out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want stick to your code, I update it somehow :

HTML :

```
      <nav>
    <div id="mySidenav">
      <ul>
          <li> <a href="#" id="about">About</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" id="blog">blog</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" id="projects">projects</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#" id="contact">contact</a></li>
      </ul>


    </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS :

```
ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;    
}
li {
float: right;
margin-left:6px;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

 a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
 }

 #mySidenav a {
 position: relative;

 transition: 0.3s;
 padding: 15px;
 width: 120px;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 100px 0 0 10px;
 text-align: right;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg); }
 #mySidenav a:hover {
  right: 0;
 -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 transform: rotate(360deg); }

#about {
background-color: #4CAF50; }

#blog { 
 background-color: #2196F3; }

 #projects {
 background-color: #f44336; }
 #contact {  
 background-color: mediumorchid; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/58dn7rw7/2/

But you need to play with your effects to get something u need.